# unauthorized access to reports in a group power bi

Tags: c#, api, powerbi

I'm trying to access the reports shared in a content pack under a group I'm a member of through the API. It seems pretty simple in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt634543.aspx, however, I get "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.". I'm able to get reports in my workspace and also the group_Id through the same api and same credentials. I have given permissions to my app to all view groups, view user groups and view content properties, which I'm not even sure if I need. Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is it still viable to you after 5 months, but if you are trying to connect to the url starting as `"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/..."`, try `"https://api.powerbi.com/beta/..."`.

I was having the same problem and changing url from `v1.0` to `beta` helped.